# Get only unique entries from pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables namely `users` and `activities` which has many to many relationships in my Laravel app. So, I have a pivot table `activity_users` with `user_id` and `activity_id`. I know that I can simply fetch all the users enrolled in an activity with a many to many relationship in my model.

But I want to get only those users from the pivot table which are enrolled in only one activity. I have been trying to do this for many days and I am still stuck. I have created a work around to filter the values based on activities_count after fetching from the database, but I wanted a more efficient solution.

##### Table `users`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | User A |
| 2 | User B |

##### Table `activities`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Activity 1 |
| 2 | Activity 2 |

##### Table `activity_users`

| activity_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

From this sample data what I want is: if I query for unique `users` in `Activity 1`, it should return only `User B` (`user_id = 2`) as he/she is not enrolled in other activities. And if I query for unique `users` in `Activity 2`, it should return `null` because it has only one `user` i.e. `User A` and he/she is already enrolled in `Activity 1`.

Fetching distinct values doesn't work as it just removes duplicates. I have already set to not allow duplicate combination of values in pivot table.

Comment: You say "as he/she is not enrolled in other activities".. which is a dependency you'll have to check with a subquery. This subquery needs to group the activities per user and only return those with exactly one activity (the one you're searching for) with `having count(*) = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing some code would help, if only to show more information on your relationships between models. But at a guess I think something like this should work:

```php
$users = User::with("activities")
    ->withCount("activities")
    ->having("activities_count", 1)
    ->whereHas("activities", fn ($q) => $q->where("activities.id", $activity_id));
```

We eager load the activities relationship and get the count as an alias, so we can catch only those with a single activity. Then we filter the relationship to search for the provided activity id.

This assumes you've set up your `User` and `Activity` models with a proper many-to-many relationship.

---

For completeness, the resulting typically (for Laravel) verbose SQL is:

```sql
SELECT `users`.*, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `activities`
    INNER JOIN `activity_user` ON `activities`.`id` = `activity_user`.`activity_id`
    WHERE `users`.`id` = `activity_user`.`user_id`
) AS `activities_count`
FROM `users` WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * from `activities`
    INNER JOIN `activity_user` ON `activities`.`id` = `activity_user`.`activity_id`
    WHERE `users`.`id` = `activity_user`.`user_id`
        AND `activities`.`id` = ?
)
HAVING `activities_count` = ?
```

Answer (score 2):

How about use Having?
You can find user with only one Activity like:

```
SELECT user_id FROM activity_users
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(user_id) = 1
```

Like [Honk der Hase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2443226/honk-der-hase) said in comments